# Allow users to post in-progress answers even to questions that get closed

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions

I was just typing an answer to a question, but as I finished, the question was closed, and I couldn't post my answer. There should be functionality that allows users to post answers they've already written, even if the questions get closed in the meantime. Why isn't there?

Comment: +1 I had the same problem. The topic was closed even though the 'best' answer was a bad answer. That's not very good, since somebody else might have the same question and use that bad answer.

Comment: Er. There is. In fact, there was just a request a few hours ago to [get rid of that feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129451/block-answering-immediately-after-question-is-closed)

Comment: That's odd, someone else posted the opposite feature request a few hours ago. EDIT: MROOOOOOOOOOOZEEEEEEEEEEKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: So what's the actual behaviour now?

Comment: Ah, I forgot; the server allows about four hours to submit the post, but as soon as your browser realizes the question has closed (it checks every 45 seconds) it disables the submit button. Why they have that disconnect is completely beyond me. So, I was going to say you have four hours, but you actually have 0-45 seconds, which isn't much time

Comment: Thanks guys, that's informative.

Comment: You could certainly only allow a longer than 45 second limit for questions where there was a draft saved.